# scanner no longer working windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printer, printing, scanning

I have a Windows 7 Professional x64 machine that no longer works with a Brother all-in-one printer/scanner when I try to scan. This happened seemingly out of nowhere.

Printing still works, but when I try to scan from Photoshop, Photoshop crashes. When I try to scan from Devices and Printers (which takes a really long time to access the printer) I get an error saying `Operation could not be completed. (error 0x00000015). The device is not ready.`

I tried uninstalling/reinstalling the printer and drivers. I have also run the Brother driver cleaner and then reinstalled and get the same results every time.

I had access to another HP all-in-one. When I set up this new printer I had a similar issue that happened. I was able to print, but when I tried to scan from the HP tool, nothing pops up.

What's going on here? Is it something with the TWAIN driver? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It was the Windows imaging aquisition (WIA) service that kept stopping.

After running sfc /scannow

from command prompt as admin all is well.