# Windows Fax and Scan does not recognize HP3055 Scanner

Tags: windows, windows-10, printer, scanner

I am running Windows 10 on a Dell T7600 Precision workstation. My all-in-one HP3055 printer/scanner has been working fine for a long time then suddenly I got an error saying that Windows Fax & Scan cannot detect the scanner. The printer works fine and the scanner driver shows in the device manager. I have uninstalled the driver and deleted the file then plugged the printer back in and installed a new driver. Still no joy. I downloaded and reinstalled all of the proper drivers from HP but none of them refer explicitly to the scanner. I restarted the WIA driver per [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/472579/scanner-no-longer-working-windows-7) and it didn't help. The printer is indicated in the control panel -> Printers & Devices but the scanner is not. SFC /scannow does not show any integrity violations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working. This is what I did. I finally found a HP3055 scanner driver using the free version of a 3rd party program called DriverMax and installed it. This still didn't solve the problem. I had my printer connected to both the USB and the network ports so I unplugged it from the network only and uninstalled everything except the PCL6 version of the printer attached to the USB. I ran the HP Print and Scan Doctor tool and could see the scanner but could not connect to it. I unplugged the printer, uninstalled the Windows Fax and Scan program by means of Programs and Features, rebooted the computer, reinstalled Windows Fax and Scan, then plugged the printer back into the USB and it was recognized. I'm not sure exactly which part of all this was the fix, but I think it was uninstalling/reinstalling Windows Fax & Scan.